# how to Specify Repeat times to repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to know about some detail of Repeater control. How can i specify the repeat counts to the repeater control.

for example i have one textbox in which user enter a digit and repeater control will show specified digit times record of repeater. How can this is possible? Can any one help.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Repeater loops the number of times that there are item in its data source. If you want it to repeat `n` times, you need a data source that has `n` items.

For example an array:

```
MyRepeater.DataSource = new int[n];
```

If you don't use the data source at all in the repeater other than to make it run a specific number of times, then you should perhaps use a simple loop instead of a repeater.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how the repeater works. It's a **data-bound** control, so you assign any `IEnumerable` (for example a List of values) and the Repeater will repeat the output for every item in the Collection.

For more information read the [MSDN article for this control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx).

For what you want to do, you can simply add the html code dynamically in a for loop.